# Mixins in loopback4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I want to add createdAt and updatedAt to each model on loopback 4

can not find name 'MixinTarget'.

Type parameter 'T' of exported function has or is using private name 'MixinTarget'.

If I try from documentation above error occurs.

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation you’re referencing to?

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-models-mixins.html in this "LoopBack 4 Approach"

Answer (score 1):

`MixinTaget` must be imported from `@loopback/core`:

```js
import {MixinTarget} from '@loopback/core';
import {Class} from '@loopback/repository';

export function TimeStampMixin<T extends MixinTarget<object>>(baseClass: T) {
  return class extends baseClass {
    // add a new property `createdAt`
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    public createdAt: Date;
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(args);
      this.createdAt = new Date();
    }
    printTimeStamp() {
      console.log('Instance created at: ' + this.createdAt);
    }
  };
}
```

### Further reading

As of the writing of this answer, the docs hasn't been updated to reflect the latest clarifications.

- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/4932c6c60c25df885b4166b7c4c425eba457a73b/docs/site/Mixin.md

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I didn't use the mixin approach. I added the following fields to my model.

```
  @property({
    type: 'date',
    default: () => new Date(),
    postgresql: {
      columnName: 'updated_at',
    },
  })
  updatedAt?: Date;
```

It should work as expected

Comment: oh ok thanks for the reply but just wanted to see how mixin works in loopback 4